# How to parse RabbitMQ's amqp request in Nginx's http consumer

Tags: http, nginx, rabbitmq, amqp

I have a design requirement where I have to process RabbitMQ's AMQP request in nginx and proxy pass it to further downstream here, nginx act as a consumer to RabbitMQ. Is there a way to convert AMQP request to http in nginx?

Request path
RMQ --amqp--> Nginx --http--> backend

Comment: it is so clear now, TY TY